# FutureWarning: Converting timezone-aware DatetimeArray to timezone-naive ndarray with 'datetime64[ns]' dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I upgraded from pandas 0.20.3 to pandas 0.24.1. While running the command `ts.sort_index(inplace=True)`, I am getting a `FutureWarning` in my test output, which is shown below. Can I change the method call to suppress the following warning? I am happy to keep the old behavior.

```
/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/sorting.py:257: FutureWarning: Converting timezone-aware DatetimeArray to timezone-naive ndarray with 'datetime64[ns]' dtype. In the future, this will return an ndarray with 'object' dtype where each element is a 'pandas.Timestamp' with the correct 'tz'.
    To accept the future behavior, pass 'dtype=object'.
    To keep the old behavior, pass 'dtype="datetime64[ns]"'.
  items = np.asanyarray(items)
```

My index looks like the following prior to running the sort_index:

```
ts.index
DatetimeIndex(['2017-07-05 07:00:00+00:00', '2017-07-05 07:15:00+00:00',
               '2017-07-05 07:30:00+00:00', '2017-07-05 07:45:00+00:00',
               ...
               '2017-07-05 08:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='start', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

I rewrote your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854900/workaround-for-pandas-futurewarning-when-sorting-a-datetimeindex), to include an MCVE.  After it went a while with no responses, I posted an issue against Pandas.

Here's my workaround:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # Bug in Pandas emits useless warning when sorting tz-aware index
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    ds = df.sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do a downgrade  using pip and setting the previous version. It's the lazier answer.
But if you really want to keep it upgraded, then there is a parameter call deprecated warning  inside pandas data frame. Just adjust it accordingly what you need. You can check it using the documentation of pandas. 
Have a nice night

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I needed to upgrade in order to get access to an updated method `to_parquet`. I'll read up on deprecated warning.

Comment: Found something ? -W ignore::DeprecationWarning should work on windows