# Workaround for Pandas FutureWarning when sorting a DateTimeIndex

Tags: pandas

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681449/futurewarning-converting-timezone-aware-datetimearray-to-timezone-naive-ndarray), Pandas.sort_index() sometimes emits a FutureWarning when doing a sort on a DateTimeIndex.  That question isn't actionable, since it contains no MCVE.  Here's one:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-07-05 07:00:00', '2018-07-05 07:15:00','2017-07-05 07:30:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['a','b','c']},index=idx)
df = df.tz_localize('UTC')
df.sort_index()
```

The warning looks like:

> FutureWarning: Converting timezone-aware DatetimeArray to
>   timezone-naive ndarray with 'datetime64[ns]' dtype

The stack (Pandas 0.24.1) is:

```
__array__, datetimes.py:358
asanyarray, numeric.py:544
nargsort, sorting.py:257
sort_index, frame.py:4795
```

The error is emitted from datetimes.py, requesting that it be called with a dtype argument.  However, there's no way to force that all the way up through nargsort -- it looks like obeying datetimes.py's request would require changes to both pandas and numpy.

Reported [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25439).  In the meantime, can you think of a workaround that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue confirmed for the 0.24.2 milestone.  Workaround is to filter the warning, thus:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # Pandas 0.24.1 emits useless warning when sorting tz-aware index
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    ds = df.sort_index()
```

Comment: Any update on a fix for this?  I'm using `pandas` 0.25.1 and I still see the same warning when doing `np.isin(df.index, df.index)` and `df.index` is a tz-aware DateTimeIndex.  Not sure whether it's the same issue or just similar.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.25.2 and am also getting these warnings - the above posted 'warnings fix' doesn't address it.