# How to plot data from a selection of columns from different Data Frames into a subplot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subplot

I want to make a subplot consisting of two line plots, and each of the two plots should plot columns from different Data Frames.

The first subplot should present all columns in one and the same Data Frame (`curves1_monthly`) as lines. The other subplot should present two columns in another Data Frame (`curves2_yearly`) as lines. Thus, the resolution of the two data sets/frames is different.

**Format of curves1_monthly:**

```
    Date                       Col1   ...     Col9
0   2000-01-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.45   ...     0.34
1   2000-02-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.56   ...     0.72
2   2000-03-01 00:00:00+01:00  0.12   ...     0.04
3   2000-04-01 00:00:00+02:00  0.57   ...     0.98
4   2000-05-01 00:00:00+02:00  0.39   ...     0.63
.   ...                        ...    ...     ...
.   ...                        ...    ...     ...
```

**Format of curves2_yearly:**

```
Date        Column1       Column2        
2000        45.50         2.40
2001        46.70         7.00
2002        50.20         1.20
2003        32.40         3.40
2004        38.90         6.90
.           .             .
.           .             .
.           .             .
```

**My plotting function:**

```
def plot_curves(curves1_monthly, curves2_yearly):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
    # First subplot: all columns in df curves1_monthly except the 
    # 'Date' col:
    for curve_name in curves1_monthly[1:]:
        curves1_monthly.plot(kind='line', y=curve_name, ax=axes[0, 
                                                                0])
    # Second subplot:
    curves2_yearly.plot(kind='line', x='Date', y='Column1', 
                                                  ax=axes[0, 1])
    curves2_yearly.plot(kind='line', x='Date', y='Column2', 
                                                  ax=axes[0, 1])
```

When I run this,

**I get this error message:**

> File "/Users/myself/.../my_program.py", line 46, in plot_curves
>       curves1_monthly.plot(kind='line', y=curve_name, ax=axes[0, 0])
>   IndexError: too many indices for array

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think in general it was just the `axes` indices that you had slightly off. When you have one row of plots, you just need to index the column number, similar to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py). Also, you can use the `plot` function from Pandas to do a lot of the work for you:

```
def plot_curves(curves1_monthly, curves2_yearly):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
    # First subplot:
    curves1_monthly.plot(kind='line', ax=axes[0])
    # Second subplot:
    curves2_yearly.plot(kind='line', x='Date', ax=axes[1])
```

Hopefully somthing similar to the following is what you were looking for:

[image]

Comment: Hm. Then I get new error messages: "/Users/.../python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:420: FutureWarning: Converting timezone-aware DatetimeArray to timezone-naive ndarray with 'datetime64[ns]' dtype. In the future, this will return an ndarray with 'object' dtype where each element is a 'pandas.Timestamp' with the correct 'tz'.
 To accept the future behavior, pass 'dtype=object'.
 To keep the old behavior, pass 'dtype="datetime64[ns]"'.
  numeric_data[col] = np.asarray(numeric_data[col])." What does this mean? I've never seen that before..

Comment: That's just a minor warning message, shouldn't actually effect your plots at all. If you want to suppress it, use the suggestion from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54937734/3763302

Comment: I think I had some other problems with my code besides the plotting. Due to some timezone issues, I couldn't plot... I have now fixed the issue, and the subplotting works. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SWatt Good to hear. No problem, happy to help!